# getRuntime.exec() can't read string

Tags: java

When I create smsGateway with gammu and java I got problem in this syntax like this:

```
try {
        Process process = runtime.exec(pathGammu+" --config "+pathConfig+" TEXT phonenumber -text \'can i send?\' ");

        InputStream is = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error : " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

When I run that syntax I have response from gammu "what is parameter: I send?"...
gammu assume "can I send?" as command... it should be a string... I was confuse

Comment: Doesn't sound like this has anything to do with runtime.exec.

Comment: btw what is the question?

Answer (score 3):

Runtime.exec doesn't parse parameters like a shell. Use the version that takes an array of strings as parameter.

See also http://m.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html

Answer (score -1):

I guess that escaping of `'` is redundant here, i.e. you should say

```
runtime.exec(pathGammu+" --config "+pathConfig+" TEXT phonenumber -text 'can i send?' ");
```

instead of

```
runtime.exec(pathGammu+" --config "+pathConfig+" TEXT phonenumber -text \'can i send?\' ");
```

Although I have not tried to run your code I think that this have a chance to work because now `'` indeed passed to OS when running command line. Otherwise it it is escaped by OS, not by Java as you probably think.

However I'd recommend you to use `ProcessBuilder` that provides more convenient and truly cross platform API for running external processes:

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder();
pb.command(pathGammu, "--config",  pathConfig, "TEXT", "phonenumber", "-text", "can i send?");
Process proc = pb.start();
```